# Why when someone releases a server-side update, it take long to appear?

Tags: server, updates, cdn, server-side

I am here to ask a question about server-side updates.

When someone makes an update to, for example: A Google Play Store app, the update does not appear immediately and takes longer for someone than for others.

Same on websites or webapps: When (for example) Google updates the YouTube server-side, they say that it may take longer to be applied to your Account.

Why does this happen? Is something about CDNs? in that case: How much time does take a CDN to replicate the content from the original server? Isn't that immediate?

Thank you so much, if I made any mistakes on the redaction, please feel free to correct them.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

the update action itself does not take much time, but when a company makes updates they do not leave them available for everyone, but only for a small group of users for test and feedback and if the group is happy with these changes, the testing circle expands and so on until these updates are available to everyone or maybe not. so that's what takes time!

Comment: How do they decide which one is going to receive the update first?

Comment: I dont know but most likely they pick them randomly from different places/countries